# VBA crashes when adding formula to multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

when using the below code my excel freezes with no error (i have to pause code and end to allow excel to be used again. - the weird thing is i can run each of the updates individually and it wll work fine. but when all of them are active it stops working.

any advice?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
With ThisWorkbook
Dim Country As String
Country = .Sheets("Views").Range("C2").Text

Select Case Country
Case Is = "Australia"
.Sheets("Views").Range("C5").Formula = "=Volume!B7+Volume!H7+Volume!N7+Volume!T7+Volume!Z7+Volume!AF7"
.Sheets("Views").Range("C6").Formula = "=Volume!C7+Volume!I7+Volume!O7+Volume!U7+Volume!AA7+Volume!AG7"
.Sheets("Views").Range("C7").Formula = "=Volume!D7+Volume!J7+Volume!P7+Volume!V7+Volume!AB7+Volume!AH7"
.Sheets("Views").Range("C8").Formula = "=Volume!E7+Volume!K7+Volume!Q7+Volume!W7+Volume!AC7+Volume!AF7"

Case Is = "China"
'do china
End Select
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Presuming that the code is in the code sheet of Sheets("Views") the Change event, once triggered, would cause  Change events by the changes it creates on the sheet, resulting in an endless loop which would, probably, eventually end in "out of memory". To avoid that,  set `Application.EnableEvents = False` before any changes are made and set the property back to `True` after all changes have been completed.

Comment: @Variatus , I presume moving the code out of the sheet into a module would also work?

Comment: Currently, the code is called automatically for *every* change in the sheet. When you put it into a module instead. you have to call it manually - via button, Keyboard-Shortcut, Immediate Window...

Comment: Suspending change events while an event procedure makes changes to a worksheet is the normal practice. Note that an event procedure can't by fired while another sheet is active. Therefore it is not necessary to specify the ActiveSheet in an event procedure. Your code seems to specify the ActiveSheet by name which makes it appear intentionally misleading by suggesting that the named sheet isn't the ActiveSheet as well as unnecessarily voluminous.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Variatus, you were 100% correct.
Presuming that the code is in the code sheet of Sheets("Views") the Change event, once triggered, would cause Change events by the changes it creates on the sheet, resulting in an endless loop which would, probably, eventually end in "out of memory". To avoid that, set Application.EnableEvents = False before any changes are made and set the property back to True after all changes have been completed. – yesterday

Answer (score 0):

I also found that adding the following at the start also helped, this way the code only trigered updates when the specific Cell i wanted changed was changed i.e. the Country selection

```
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C2"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
'code you want exicuted
End If
```